# Creating a loop with an IF variable -- Run-time error '1004'

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a loop based on data in Column L. Data in Column L is formatted as Text and contains dates. If a match is found, the entire Row has to be highlighted in yellow.

```
Sub Forn()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    
    Dim strSearchText As String
    strSearchText = Format(DateAdd("m", 2, Now()), "yyyymm") 
    Dim rngSearchArea As Range
    Set rngSearchArea = ws.Range(Range("L10"), ws.Range("L" & ws.Range("L:L").Cells.Count).End(xlUp))
    
    Dim strFirstFound As String
    Dim rngCurrentFound As Range
    Set rngCurrentFound = ws.Range("L10")
    Set rngCurrentFound = rngSearchArea.Find(What:=strSearchText, After:=rngCurrentFound, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
            LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
            MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False)
            
             If rngCurrentFound Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "INGEN TREFF"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    rngCurrentFound.Resize(1, 16).Offset(0, -11).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
    
    strFirstFound = rngCurrentFound.Address

Dim rngSource As Range
Dim rngNextFound As Range

Do
     Set rngNextFound = rngSearchArea.FindNext(rngCurrentFound)
     If rngNextFound.Row > rngCurrentFound.Row Then
        rngCurrentFound.Resize(1, 16).Offset(0, -11).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
    Else
         Set rngSource = ws.Range(rngCurrentFound, ws.UsedRange.Cells(ws.UsedRange.Cells.Count))
         
    End If

    Set rngCurrentFound = rngSearchArea.FindNext(rngCurrentFound)
    
Loop While rngCurrentFound.Address <> strFirstFound

End Sub
```

> I'm getting Run-time error '1004':
> Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed.

This exact same code worked for me yesterday and I'm at a complete loss as to what needs to be changed here.

UPD: the error is caused by launching the Macro from PERSONAL.XLSB --

```
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
```

no longer works as needed.

Comment: Which line errors?

Comment: Set rngSearchArea = ws.Range(Range("L10"), ws.Range("L" & ws.Range("L:L").Cells.Count).End(xlUp))

Comment: Have you changed the order of sheets? You're looking at `Worksheets(1)` rather than a named sheet.

Comment: There's only 1 sheet

Comment: The problem is apparently caused by launching the Macro from Personal.xlsb and the ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1) no longer works. Any workarounds?

Comment: `ThisWorkbook`  is the Workbook where the code lives. If you move code to `Personal`, it will access the first sheet of `Personal` - which probably don't exists.

Comment: Your missing a `ws`. It should be this: `Set rngSearchArea = ws.Range(ws.Range("L10"), ws.Range("L" & ws.Range("L:L").Cells.Count).End(xlUp))`. You forgot to qualify the worksheet for `Range("L10")`

Comment: @FunThomas How do I make a valid reference to the first worksheet in Personal? Whenever the macro is going to be launched from Personal, it will always apply to the first worksheet of the workbook from where the macro was launched.

Comment: @smgrd `Workbooks("Personal.xlsb").Worksheets(1)` should work, but you might want to use `Workbooks("Personal.xlsb").Worksheets.Count` first

Comment: If you mean the Worksheet that *called* the Macro, then you need to either include that information in the Function Call, *or* hope that it's the `ActiveWorkbook`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `ThisWorkbook` in a macro tells VBA that you want to access the workbook where the code is stored. If you move your code to the `Personal.xlsb`, it will access `Personal.xlsb` and it's sheets - and that's probably not what you want.

You put a macro in the `Personal` usually to have it available all the time, e.g. via a Keyboard shortcut.

If you want the code to work on the currently visible workbook, replace `ThisWorkbook` simply by `ActiveWorkbook` - but you need to ensure that it makes sense to run the macro on that workbook.

If you want to execute it always on the same workbook, it makes no sense to have it in the personal - just keep it in the workbook itself.

If you want to select the workbook first, add a fileopen-dialog to your code, open the workbook using `Workbooks.Open` and use the workbook-reference returned by the open-command.